# How to manage references - Mongodb backend, Javascript frontend

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This is a generic question for an example app I was playing with. I am using Mongodb for persistence and Vanilla javascript on client.

I basically create an object from user input and then send the object to server in only one call, there are relations in my object so I have to generate Guid as Ids and manage reference on base of that.

```
{
    "school": {
        "courses": [
          {"id": 1,"name": "course1"},
          {"id": 2,"name": "course2"},
          {"id": 2,"name": "course3"}
        ],
        "students": [
          {"id": 1,"name": "student1"},
          {"id": 2,"name": "student2"},
          {"id": 3,"name": "student3"}
        ],
        "groups": [
         {"id": 1,"students": [1, 3],"course": 1},
         {"id": 2,"students": [2, 3],"course": 2}  
        ]
    }
}
```

This is simplified object and also using ints for Id instead of Guid.

A user will first add some courses, then add some students and then on next screen they will be shown drop downs filled with courses and students added earlier.

User will create groups, selecting students(multiselect) and a course. Here I will use the Ids generated for courses and students as reference.

Now at this point it is all working fine, I create the object and send data back to server to be saved in Mongodb.

The problem occurs when user deletes some course or student, while I still have that student or course's reference in some group, how can I auto update the group then. I know I can use a loop or some thing like that but that just don't seem right. And in original data I have very complex relations so that approach won't really be reasonable.

Comment: Typically, since the client cannot be trusted, it should send everything except the UUID and let the server generate one. If you need that ID back on the client, just have the server respond with the final record.

Comment: Actually I can't, have to manage everything on client side. App is kinda offline.

Comment: If I have to create relationships in this way (with document databases) I cross reference them between documents. So when the `group` has an array of `students`, the `student` also has an array of `groups`. This array is populated when a student is added to a group so that when you delete the student you can accurately clean-up references. I'd love to find a better way, but it might just be 'switch to a relational database'.